# I moved files to NTFS and cant start GUI in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: mount, ntfs

The problem showed up when i moved folders with cache to my ntfs drive and made symbolic links to it (don't quite remember exact locations of them `/var/cache` , `/var/tmp` I guess also `/home/roman/.cache` and so on)

When i restarted the system it booted in terminal (didnt start desktop environment)
I thought that its becouse my ntfs drive is not mounting at the startup so i mounted it to the same place as it was mounting before used `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/roman/R`  (and i succeed because i entered to the folder `cd /var/cache` which i could not enter when it was not mounted)

Than i used `startx` command thought it going to start but it didnt !

Any suggestions to a noob user ?

Comment: NTFS cannot handle Linux permissions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use NTFS for Unix system files and directories. NTFS has very different semantics of owner/permission; an awful lot of system files in `/var/` depend on the exact unix semantics. Sadly, moving folders and file from `/var` destroyed the information of user/group/permissions...

The problem you have now is similar to this: [How to recover after all files are deleted from /var folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549101/how-to-recover-after-all-files-are-deleted-from-var-folder#comment752309_549101) ; I suggest you follow the [@Rinzwind answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/549121/16395).

Comment: Thank you for your aswer !
So there is no way to move cache folders to ntfs drive ? I whant to do this because dont whant that to be stored on my SSD which is drive of the root system !?

Comment: You can't use NTFS for anything that need Unix semantics. Most personal documents, photos, music etc is normally ok. Caches and system temporary file, generally no - could be on case for case base. Just the case insensitiveness of NTFS can be a problem.

Comment: You can create a separate ext4 partition on your HDD and move & mount the Linux folders there.

Answer (score -1):

Is your disk being mounted  on startup automatically? make sure the disk mounts itself by editing the entry in /etc/fstab. or try reconfiguring the package using

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

you may have to Install this package if system doesn't find it at all.

Good Luck.

Comment: Its not starting automatically ! I found in the internet 2 ways to make it happen: one is to gedit fstab but it needs GUI and other is to type command udisks --mount /dev/sda1  but it says that there is not usdisks installed and gives me command apt-get install udisks when i enter that it states that there is no such command install !
Can you point me to right link how to edit that /etc/fstab from terminal only ?
Thank you for the aswer buy the way !

Comment: Ok so i made it automount now by editing /etc/fstab by nano filemanager! Cheked and it really mounts at the start !
Any new suggestions !?