# How to entirely backup Ubuntu Server to another Ubuntu Server (broken disk sever 1, for example)

Tags: server, backup, restore

I have a little question for You. I manage a little dedicated server with **Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS** installed.

I have searched a lot, but I don't found a solid and in first **SIMPLE** solution for backup my server to another server.

**More details:** I use Wordpress, Apache, Php, 2 Mysql Databases and SFTP services. Inside there are one domain and one subdomain active.

**The question is**: I just implemented a backup solution only for my websites contents. But in case the disk will be broken, for example, **is there a way to backup all entire server** (for example once a month) files and installed program (including the Operational System) and creat a kind of file that I can use to restore all the *configurations/files/installed program* **in another server**?

**I have no fisic access to the server, and I don't have a Snapshot service avaible with the Hosting (Kimsufi).**

I have found this suggest but I can't access to the GRUB: [Tar solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524418/how-would-i-use-tar-for-full-backup-and-restore-with-system-on-ssd-and-home-on-h).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of tools you can use to copy filesystems around such as `dd` or `rsync`

**rsync**

Allows for copying over ssh

Copy your home directory to another server via ssh

```
rsync -a --delete --quiet -e ssh /folder/to/backup remoteuser@remotehost:/location/of/backup
```

Ful System backup

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /path/to/backup/folder
```

And finally rsync as a disk cloning tool

```
rsync -qaHAXS SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR
```

from the man page

```
-H, --hard-links      preserve hard links
-A, --acls            preserve ACLs (implies -p)
-X, --xattrs          preserve extended attributes
-S, --sparse          handle sparse files efficiently
```

**dd**

I don't think you can use dd over ssh so you'll have to use a script to upload the file or just copy over to a usb stick but disk cloning (what I think you're asking about) is what dd was designed for

Clone an entire disk

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

you might be able to try this workaround for using dd over an ssh tunnel though my advice would be to test it on a couple of vm's first before running it on bare metal as while `dd` is a powerful tool as uncle ben said 'With great power, comes great responsibility' it's easy to destroy filesystems with dd. Without further adieu... the workaround

```
ssh server1 'dd if=/some/file' | ssh server2 'dd of=/new/file/path'
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your reaply. I have searched for dd but i readed that we must use a usb pendrive. I haven't a fisic access to the server.

Comment: after a little googling around it looks like there are workarounds to use dd over ssh I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thank You j-money! So with rsync I can take another server, install the same operational system and make the Full System backup command, right? Just it? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I undersantd your question :( I use both rsync and dd on my systems. I use rsync as a full system backup (not nessciarily a disk clone) as it saves alot of important files not caputred by my regular backup scripts. To use rsync as you want you may try `rsync -qaHAXS SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR` But i will update the answer to reflect this better

Comment: My intent is to avoid to reinstall e configure another server with same programms, files and settings if an unexpected event happens to the main server. Specially i don't like to reconfigure all settings of the website (php, apache, https, etc)